# AngularJS and orderby in ng-repeat with special characters

Tags: angularjs, localization, sql-order-by

I am having trouble ordering strings containing characters that are not in the English alphabet ( š,č,ž,..)

Here is the fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vhhgh/

The letters are from the Slovenian alphabet.

Answer (score 8):

It's been a while, but I found other solution: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vhhgh/10/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='test'>
  <h2>Users</h2>
  <div ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="user in users | localeCompareString">
        {{user.surname}} {{user.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  var test=angular.module('test',[])
.controller('UsersCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [
    {name:'Ben', surname:'Živkovič'},
    {name:'Ken', surname:'AlGore'},
    {name:'Erica', surname:'Červ'},
    {name:'Jane', surname:'Šinigoj'},
    {name:'Kevin', surname:'Sort'},
    {name:'Roger', surname:'Willson'},
    {name:'Kim', surname:'Zorro'}
];
}]).filter('localeCompareString',function(){
    return function (items) {
         //window.console.log(items);
        items.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.surname.localeCompare(b.surname);
        });
        return items;
      }; 
});

})(window.angular);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordering arrays of strings with "foreign" letters isn't as easy to do as you might think. Actally, it can be a right pain in the ... to get right. The problem boils down to the fact that the Unicode charset contains (pretty much) all charactrers in existance, so a universal lexicographical sorting isn't possible since different countries all have different ways they expect the sorting to be handled.

To get around this, I've found [TCollator](http://www.indiscripts.com/post/2010/10/alphabetical-sort-in-javascript-and-indesign), a small library aiming at fixing that issue, very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two strings with the String.localeCompare() method. It's then easy to create your own filter to sort your array:

```
MyApp.filter('myOrderBy', function () {
return function (array, property, reverse) {
    var result = array.sort(function (object1, object2) {
        if (angular.isUndefined(property)) {
            return object1.localeCompare(object2);
        }

        return object1[property].localeCompare(object2[property]);
    });

    return reverse ? result.reverse() : result;
};
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Starting from AngularJS 1.5.7, orderBy takes an optional comparator function. [The docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/api/ng/filter/orderBy) contain an example involving a locale-sensitive comparator.